# MySQL n results per GROUP BY, Order by count

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

[image: MySQL n results per GROUP BY, Order by count]

`Country` - `Company` have a 1-n relationship.

`Company` - `Dish` have a n-n relationship.

I need to get the Dishes from each locale ordered descending based of their count in the respective locale, each locale having 100 results.

So far I have

```
SELECT dishes.title,
       dishes.name,
       dishes.id,
       countries.locale
FROM countries 
    JOIN companies ON companies.`country_id` = countries.`id`
    JOIN company_dish  ON company_dish.`company_id` = companies.`id`
    JOIN dishes  ON company_dish.`dish_id` = dishes.`id`
GROUP BY dishes.`title`, countries.locale
ORDER BY ??? count_dishes_in_each_locale ?? DESC
```

**Sample data:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us your code.  Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Updated with the progress so far

Comment: Share sample data and desired output in formatted text

Comment: Is this homework? Look at aggregate functions - count, sum, avg etc.

Comment: @zarruq desired output http://prntscr.com/go9byc , sample data http://prntscr.com/go9di9

Comment: What is `company_newdish`? What is `dishes.slug`? Please edit your question and re-read it thoroughly so that your code does not contradict your picture any more. Alternatively, show us your table definitions (`SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`).

Comment: @Binarus company_dish is the pivot table between companies and dishes (n - n relation) . `dishes.slug` was supposed to be `dishes.title` , my bad

Comment: Yes, I have understood what `company_dish` is. But what is `company_newdish`? And `dishes.title` isn't in your picture as well, but probably that's a minor problem.

Comment: @Mike: Sample Data in formatted text please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with sub request...

Your request :

```
SELECT
    dishes.title,
    dishes.name,
    dishes.id,
    countries.locale,
    countries_count.dishes_nb
FROM countries 
    JOIN companies ON companies.`country_id` = countries.`id`
        JOIN company_dish ON company_dish.`company_id` = companies.`id`
            JOIN dishes ON company_dish.`dish_id` = dishes.`id`
    JOIN
        ({SubRequest}) countries_count ON countries_count.`country_id` = countries.`id`
ORDER BY
    countries_count.dishes_nb DESC
```

and the sub request, count dishes by country :

```
SELECT
    countries.id AS country_id,
    COUNT(company_dish.dish_id) AS country_dishes_nb
FROM countries 
    JOIN companies ON companies.country_id = countries.id
        JOIN company_dish ON company_dish.company_id = companies.id
GROUP BY
    country_id
```

or to count for each dish by country :

Your request :

```
SELECT
    dishes.title,
    dishes.name,
    dishes.id,
    countries.locale,
    countries_count.dishes_nb
FROM countries 
    JOIN companies ON companies.`country_id` = countries.`id`
        JOIN company_dish ON company_dish.`company_id` = companies.`id`
            JOIN dishes ON company_dish.`dish_id` = dishes.`id`
    JOIN
        ({SubRequest}) countries_count ON countries_count.`country_id` = countries.`id`
        AND countries_count.`dish_id` = dishes.`id`
ORDER BY
    countries_count.dishes_nb DESC
```

and the sub request :

```
SELECT
    countries.id AS country_id,
    dishes.id AS dish_id,
    COUNT(company_dish.dish_id) AS country_dishes_nb
FROM countries 
    JOIN companies ON companies.country_id = countries.id
        JOIN company_dish ON company_dish.company_id = companies.id
            JOIN dishes ON company_dish.dish_id = dishes.id) AS countries_count ON countries_count.country_id` = countries.`id`
GROUP BY
    country_id, dish_id
```

And concat(replace) in {SubRequest}